# How to Execute following query in R

Tags: r

I have a query which i want to analyze in r studio. The Following query is:

```
SELECT D.Company,E.MachineType,E.MachineRequired,D.BulletinID,D.UseDate,D.daycnt,D.Line,D.FileRefID,D.OrderRef,D.Style FROM(
  SELECT Company,BulletinID,Count(Line) daycnt,UseDate,FileRefID,orderref,Line ,style FROM (
    SELECT x.Line, x.orderref, x.UseDate, x.Company, x.BulletinID,x.FileRefID,c.StyleName style FROM(
      SELECT Line, Orderref, UseDate, BulletinID, filerefid, Company FROM (
        SELECT Line,orderref,usedate,m.BulletinID,filerefid,M.Company FROM (
          SELECT Factory, b.[Line No] Line,[Order Ref] orderref,fm.dbo.dateonly(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) usedate,[BisFileID] filerefid  
          FROM BitopiSplint.dbo.['os-2$'] b
          WHERE  b.[Date]=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) b
        JOIN (SELECT BulletinID,FileRef,Company FROM ProcessOBmaster) m on b.filerefid=m.FileRef ) t)x
    INNER JOIN FileRef fr on x.FileRefId=fr.FileRefID
    INNER JOIN Style_Master c on fr.StyleID=c.StyleId)T
  GROUP BY Company,BulletinID,UseDate,orderref,FileRefID,Line,style)D
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MachineType, d.BulletinID,sum(isnull(PlannedWs,0))MachineRequired 
  From  ProcessOBDetails as d 
  JOIN [BitopiSplint].[dbo].[tblOperationCategory_Details] n on d.MachineType=n.ItemName and isnull(n.IsDashBoadApplicable,0)=1
  WHERE isnull(MachineType,'')!=''  
  GROUP BY d.BulletinID,MachineType)E on D.BulletinID=E.BulletinID
```

but how to execute it r and use as a data frame can anyone help me. Even it is possible to execute such query in r.

ODBC connection has been setup for the server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vAbs.png)

Comment: it is hard to answer this without knowing what your query is doing. can you post an example dataset and the desired output for that exmple so we can help?

Comment: Company MachineType MachineRequired BulletinID UseDate daycnt Line FileRefID OrderRef Style
02 1N2TBT-PG 4 B-18-1315 3/27/2019 0:00 1 2330 FR-18-366 PR-19-173 JADE HIGH OL BOWERY S.9
02 1N2TLS-EC 3 B-18-1315 3/27/2019 0:00 1 2330 FR-18-366 PR-19-173 JADE HIGH OL BOWERY S.9

Comment: please put this in the question in a better format. it is not user-friendly at all in the comment section

Comment: It is creation simple data set in SQL where it contains columns Company, Machine Name, Machine Required, Bulletin ID, Use Date, Daycnt, Line, File Ref ID and Style

Comment: Try `dbGetQuery(conn, statement)`

Comment: I was adding picture for the better understanding. But your dbGetQuery makes it simple. Thanks Buddy you are superb